# Why My Gps through draw map is freezing my Application

Tags: android, service, google-api

I am creating `Walk through draw path on google map v2 in android` just like **runtastic App**.

**Requirement:**

```
-> Draw Path ever 10 second.
-> update Distance between start and current location.
-> Update time
-> Many more..
```

Application is **working on background also** but if application is **run more then 30 minute** then `application and phone is freez/hang.`

I think problem is `drawing map and calculating some stuff.`

please give me some **solution or stuff** so i can improve this thing in my application.

```
I am work with last 2-3 days but not find out any proper solution.
```

**Update:**

[Reference App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.highwaynorth.jogtracker) like this way i want to develop application.

All of the task is done but freezing application is big issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use Broadcast Receiver, Calculate the distance when phone in on screen mode when phone in off screen mode stop the calculation i hope it will work fine.

Comment: thanks  I am already used broadcast Receiver for calculating distance,and more/